# Event listener inside event handler doesn't bind the correct this

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

To make this simple, I have two "classes", "Calendar" and "EventHandler".  Calendar inits an `EventHandler` at the constructor and then all the `addeventlisteners` are like this:

```
this.cDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", this.eventHandler.calMousedown.bind(this));
```

That all works, it gets to the event handler just fine and this is properly the calendar object.  Now, in the `eventhandler` handler, `calMousedown` in the example above, it adds a further `eventListener`:

```
this.cDiv.addEventListener("mousemove", this.eventHandler.calMousemove(evt).bind(this));
```

As far as my understanding goes, inside `calMousedown`, this was bound to the `Calendar` object, so when I further bind this inside `calMousedown`, it should also bind the `Calendar` object to `calMousemove`.  But it isn't.  This, in `calMousemove`, is the `EventHandler` object.  So, what did I do incorrectly and is there a way for me to bind the proper this (`Calendar` object) inside the event handler?

Comment: If `calMousemove` is the handler you want bound, you shouldn't be invoking it. If your concern was to pass on the `evt` object, then `this.eventHandler.calMousemove.bind(this, evt)`

Comment: If `evt` is the current event object, keep in mind that your `mousemove` handler will receive both that and its own event object, which seems wrong.

Comment: I don't want to bind evt, just pass it as an argument -- or is it passed automatically?  I want this, in all cases, to point to the Calendar object, never to the EventHandler object.

Comment: So, removing the (evt) sending in the addEventListener seems to have worked, it gets evt automatically.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.